# How to disable a display a view based on the user privilege?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse-RCP application where I have three views.One of the view is an Admin View which should be visible only to a specific users.

In my application I have a feature called Reset Perspective which goes and resets the perspective (Providing Appropriate Views) for the users by checking their privilege.

Now in one system I logged in as an admin,I am able to see the admin view.This is perfect.Now I logged out ,another user tries to login (he doesn't have admin privilege) ,but he is also able to see the Admin view.Only after resetting the view the admin view is getting disappeared.

I believe while launching the application it is looking at the workbench of that application and accordingly loading different views.How can we check the what views are being loaded to application initially so that we restrict that based on different user.

Comment: The simpest thing to do would be to use the `-clearPersistedState` flag so that the RCP always starts with initial perspective/views shown.